# Amazon’s AWS ability to perform a firewall rule, based on the source IP ports

Tags: amazon-ec2

Microsoft Azure has security groups, which allow filtering on the source IP ports.  Does Amazon’s AWS have the same feature, to program from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only does it have it, it is also called the same. It can be accessed by downloading the AWS CLI. Most of the commands relating to security groups will be in [aws ec2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/), for example [aws ec2 describe-security-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html).
Some of the commands in pertaining to security groups can be fairly confusing so you might want to look at the GUI before your first time, and reading the docs will be helpful (as it usually is).